# Uncaught TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.from is not a function

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to create a unit test in angular-6.

```
import { TodosComponent } from './todos.component';
import { TodoService } from './todo.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';

describe('TodosComponent', () => {
  let component: TodosComponent;
  let service: TodoService;

  beforeEach(() => {
      service = new TodoService(null);
      component = new TodosComponent(service);
  });

  it('should set todo property with the item returned from', () => {

    const todos = [1, 2, 3];
      spyOn(service, 'getTodos').and.callFake(() => {
        return Observable.from([[
            {id: 1, title: 'a'},
            {id: 2, title: 'b'},
            {id: 3, title: 'c'}
        ]]);
      });

      component.ngOnInit();

      expect(component.todos.length).toBe(todos);

  });

});
```

I am getting error `Uncaught TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.from is not a function`

```
"rxjs": "^6.0.0",
```

Comment: Since RxJS 6 use pipable operators https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: `import { from } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: Use pipeable operators. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: @martin, how can I use import { from } from 'rxjs';, in my code section, it is giving error,  Property 'from' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by others, since Angular 6 which uses Rxjs6, you will have to import `from` from 'rxjs' and use it directly without doing `Observable.from`

Change your implementation to the following:

```
import { TodosComponent } from './todos.component';
import { TodoService } from './todo.service';
import { Observable, from  } from 'rxjs';

describe('TodosComponent', () => {
  let component: TodosComponent;
  let service: TodoService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    service = new TodoService(null);
    component = new TodosComponent(service);
  });

  it('should set todo property with the item returned from', () => {

    const todos = [1, 2, 3];
    const data = [{
        id: 1,
        title: 'a'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'b'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'c'
      }
    ];
    spyOn(service, 'getTodos').and.callFake(() => {
      return from([data]);
    });

    component.ngOnInit();

    expect(component.todos.length).toBe(todos);

  });

});
```